# which words in a title should capitalized?

Tags: single-word-requests

are there any concrete rules  that say wich words(parts of speech) in a title should start  with a  capital ? what would be a correct capitalization for the title of this question ?

Answer (score 0):

In titles, you always capitalize everything except for words like 'the,' 'a,' 'and,' etc, unless one of them is the first word in the sentence.  [This](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/022702CapsInTitles.htm) has worked well for me in the past if I wasn't sure how to capitalize titles.

For your question, it should be:

> Which Words in a Title Should Be Capitalized,

if I'm not mistaken.